# Node types: Everything looks like text. And not very interesting text at that. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drag-and-drop

I have a UL of LI's, each containing an IMG and a SPAN containing some brief text, and my code that is intended to display the SPAN if someone mouses over the IMG, is looking and finding only TEXT nodes.

The code, up to a certain point, is:

```
drag.mousemove = function (event) {
   if (event == null) {
       event = window.event;
   }
   var lowest_distance = +Infinity;
   var lowest_distance_index = null;
   var root = document.getElementById('path1');
   if (!root) {
       return;
   }
   var intermediate = root.childNodes;
   var images = [];
   var best_image = null;
   for (var outer = 0; outer < intermediate.length; ++outer) {
       console.log('Outer: ' + intermediate[outer].nodeName);
   }
}
```

And the only thing it ever reports is "Outer: #text". The path1 DIV contains any images that are dragged on to it; from a browser behavior perspective it looks like the images have been successfully dragged and dropped and lost the SPANs along the way. But the console doesn't get on to the inner loop of the child nodes of path1; following what I quoted is an "Inner: " logged traversal of childNodes to an outer childNode, and I don't remember ever seeing an "Inner: " in the logs. When I logged the contents of the nodes, they were all a line break and eight spaces, no tab.

And, in the HTML source, the entire contents between the opening and closing DIV tags for path1 is a line break and eight spaces, no tab.

Is there a sensible way to have a drag and drop that works for images and is intended to move (in this case) a containing LI to the target area, but DOM inspection finding only text nodes? Is there a reason, alternately, that would freeze the initial DOM contents as the only thing that will ever be recognized?

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) representative snippet in a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar? Then we can try and see what's going on.

Comment: If you have a node text and want its text, use `.nodeValue` instead of `.nodeName`

Comment: If you want only text nodes, you should check if each node's `.nodeType` is 3